# How can I create my own public certificate using openssl?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, rsa

I have a public key/private key pair i generated using two primes p and q. I now need to use openssl to sign and create the certificate. I heard req utility and wrote this from the man pages.

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -nodes -key inputfile.txt -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

But what details should I specify in inputfile.txt and is there a particular format for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's nice walkthrough of all the steps you need to do in order to generate self-signed ceritficate.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

You are using wrong parameters. When you are generating new certificate, you've got two inputs - request and private key and one output - the signed certificate.
The correct command therefore would be:
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt`
where

- x509 req : you are requesting PKI functionality
- days 365 : validitity period for the certificate
- in : certificate signing request
- signkey : private key used to sign the certificate
- out : output file for the generated certificate

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually for *selfsigned* you can do it in one step by *combining* the `-new` and `-x509` options of `req`. Separate `req` and `x509`, or sometimes better `ca`, are needed to implement a (private) CA structure.

Answer (score 1):

`req -x509` (without `-new`) requires a CSR on input and you don't say anything about having created a CSR. `-key` requires a "private-key" file (which in the PKCS#1 CRT form which OpenSSL uses is really keypair) and you say you have that, although it would not normally use a .txt extension. `-keyout` and `-nodes` are useless when `-key` is input; they are for the case where `req` *generates* a new keypair along with the CSR or cert.

You may want to use `req -new -x509` which in effect generates a CSR for your keypair and name and then converts it to a *self-signed* cert automatically. For that you need to supply the subject Distinguished Name (commonly Organization, CommonName, and so on, but can be configured) and validity, and optionally but usually cert extensions, which vary depending on what your cert is intended for, either in a config file, which can either be specified or use a default that depends on your build/package, or commandline options, or a combination of both.

Did you try reading the manpages for `req` and for `x509v3_config` to which it refers? There's a reason those total 15 kilobytes which I don't propose to retype here.